# Join error: #1052 - Column 'TaskID' in field list is ambiguous

Tags: sql, join

TRYING TO JOIN THESE 3 TABLES but getting  #1052 - Column 'TaskID' in field list is ambiguous. please help

```
select P.ProjectColor,TimeCardID,UserName,TaskName,TaskID,MAX (Punch), TotalHours,Running,LASTUPDATE 
from T_TIMECARD as E, T_TASK as A, T_PROJECT AS P 
where   E.TaskID = A.TaskID
AND P.ProjectID = A.ProjectID
group by Punch 
order by Punch desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Learn to use explicit `join` syntax.  The problem is caused because the column is the same in both tables.  Yes, they `=` suggests they have the same values, but you have to be explicit:

```
Select P.ProjectColor, TimeCardID, UserName, TaskName, A.TaskID,
      MAX(Punch), TotalHours, Running, LASTUPDATE 
from T_TIMECARD E JOIN
     T_TASK A
     ON E.TaskID = A.TaskID JOIN
     T_PROJECT P
     ON P.ProjectID = A.ProjectID
group by  P.ProjectColor, TimeCardID, UserName, TaskName, A.TaskID, TotalHours, Running, LASTUPDATE 
order by MAX(Punch) desc;
```

Your `group by` should also mention all the columns not in aggregation columns.

Comment: IT WORKS,  SELECT P.ProjectColor, TimeCardID, UserName, TaskName, A.TaskID, MAX( Punch ) AS LASTUDATE, TotalHours, Running
FROM T_TIMECARD E
JOIN T_TASK A ON E.TaskID = A.TaskID
JOIN T_PROJECT P ON P.ProjectID = A.ProjectID
GROUP BY P.ProjectColor, TimeCardID, UserName, TaskName, A.TaskID, TotalHours, Running
ORDER BY MAX( Punch ) DESC

Answer (score 0):

The select clause is referencing `TaskID`, but it doesn't know if you mean `E.TaskID` or `A.TaskID`. You need to be specific and alias all the columns in your select clause that occur in more than one table.

You will also have problems with the `group by`: if grouping by `punch`, then all other columns in the select clause other than `punch` must be aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

Use alias....

```
select P.ProjectColor,TimeCardID,UserName,TaskName,  **A.TaskID**  ,MAX (Punch),   

TotalHours,Running,LASTUPDATE 

from T_TIMECARD as E, T_TASK as A, T_PROJECT AS P 
where   E.TaskID = A.TaskID
AND P.ProjectID = A.ProjectID

group by Punch 
order by Punch desc;
```

Comment: i made some changes and now it is telling no database selected

Comment: select P.ProjectColor,TimeCardID,UserName,TaskName,A.TaskID,MAX(Punch) as LastUpdate, TotalHours,Running
from T_TIMECARD as E, T_TASK as A, T_PROJECT AS P 
where E.TaskID = A.TaskID
AND P.ProjectID = A.ProjectID
group by Punch
order by Punch desc;

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS RECENT_TIMECARD;

CREATE VIEW RECENT_TIMECARD AS

SELECT P.ProjectColor, TimeCardID, UserName, TaskName, A.TaskID, MAX( Punch ) AS LASTUDATE, TotalHours, Running
FROM T_TIMECARD E
JOIN T_TASK A ON E.TaskID = A.TaskID
JOIN T_PROJECT P ON P.ProjectID = A.ProjectID
GROUP BY P.ProjectColor, TimeCardID, UserName, TaskName, A.TaskID, TotalHours, Running
ORDER BY MAX( Punch ) DESC
```